# Finding adjacent MGRS blocks/grids?

Tags: coordinate-system, algorithm, mgrs

My requirement is that, say I'm given a [MGRS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Military_Grid_Reference_System) grid (100mX100m), I now need the IDs of all the 8 MGRS grids around the one that was given.

One way that is being suggested is as follows.

1. Compute the lat-long for the given MGRS block
2. Move 100m in each of the eight direction and find the MGRS block of new lat-long

Though the above method is full-proof (or so to speak), is highly inefficient for my use case.

Is there any other method?

I'm OK, with little bit of hard-coding or maintaining a reference dump (but not too huge, like for all the MGRS).

Comment: What software do you want to use? In which format are you working? Could you edit your question so it is clear what you want to do and the tools you have in your disposal?

Comment: Some MGRS implementations might be flexible enough to correct the MGRS string if you give it the wrong one. Because MGRS is built of a combo of lat/lon and UTM values moving 100 m could be in the next latitude band or the next zone.

Comment: Note that mgrs grids that are on the border of a Zone might not and will not exactly line up with neighboring mgrs grids.